# Check if a Row Range Contains another Row Range values in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, search, find

I have an Excel file that contains two different columns having Customer Numbers (let's say CustomerA and CustomerB columns). What I would like to do to check which of the CustomerA values match the CustomerB values. Is it possible?

**Update**

@sancho.s: Here is the excel file and values I used.There is no error and no value as you mentioned on your answer. But after changing some values in the formula I get error "There is an error in teh formula...". Thanks for your kind help.

```
    A             B                         C               D
1   CustA         InB
2   6077890       =MATCH(A2,$D$2:$D$5,0)                   6077890
3   48414792                                               5861291
4   50267662                                               3082960
5   51242034
6   6079377
7   6077580
```

Comment: When you say match what exactly do you mean? Do mean match the adjacent customer, or do you want to know whether a given customer in column A exists in column B?

Comment: @CLockeWork: I mean "if all of the customers in column A exists in column B". Thanks.

Comment: @Chenmunka : I have an excel workbook. There are 2 columns; ColumnA and ColumnB. There are 3 customer numbers (i.e. 100,101,102) in ColumnA. There are 100 records (customer numbers) in ColumnB. I want to search all the ColumnA values in ColumnB. Is it clear?

Comment: @H.Johnson - Please specify: 1) What results you get in B2:B7 when copying the formula in B2, 2) What is the exact formula that gives you the error quoted.

Comment: @sancho.s: Dear Sancho, I added the file on this link: http://wikisend.com/download/290184/check.xlsx I think there is no need to take your time and you can try/test on it. Thanks.

Comment: @H.Johnson - Please post the requested info, it makes the best use of SU and has a good chance of providing with needed input.

Comment: @sancho.s: Regarding to your question on your prior message: 
1) There is no result on B2-B7 after using the given formula on B2. 2) Normally there is no result and no error using as mentioned above. But, when I edit the formula I encounter an error message indicating that "there is an error on formula". Is it enough? Thanks.

Comment: No. Please: 1) It looks strange that "there is no result" ([it should be either an integer or #N/A](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/match-function-HP010062414.aspx). Did you copy the formula in B2 and paste in cells B3-B7? 2) "When I edit...": What is the modified formula that gives you the error? I guess the one I posted works ok for you.

Comment: @sancho.s: I tried the excel file on the office page and saw the usage. Although there is no such a kind of search function for a range of cell, your answer is the most likely and thank you very much for your consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With reference to the figure

[image]

cell B2 has `=MATCH(A2,$D$2:$D$5,0)`. It gives the row number in range D2:D5 (relative to the upper row in the range) where each customer number first appears. If a given Customer ID is not present in column D (e.g., delete cell D5), you will get `#N/A` (in B3 in this case).

Then you copy formula from B2 to other cells in column B. It is easy to adapt the formulas for expanded customer lists.

Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 for a solution that not only tells you if it exists, but also tells you where... awesome :D

Comment: @CLockeWork: Thanks for reply. But I cannot provide this using the file here: http://we.tl/gn5FW8AIdd Could you please check it?

Comment: @H.Johnson - It was sancho.s (me) who answered. I cannot check the link you provided. I suggest you post a text version of the worksheet you have and the results you want to obtain (see [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20355637/2707864)), and explain why the answer provided is not useful for you.

Comment: @sancho.s: I updated the question by description. Muchas gracias :)